# How can I change my Windows desktop background without administrator rights?

Tags: windows, desktop-customization, non-admin

How can I change my desktop wallpaper to something I prefer when I don't have administrator rights?

I'm using Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Create a new folder `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\background`
- Add `background.html` and your `background.png`
- Insert the following into `background.html`:
  `<html>`
  `<img src="background.png" alt="Selfhtml">`
  `</html>`
- Open `background.html` with Firefox
- Right-click on the image 
  `-->` Set as background
   
  [image: img2]
- Voilà, your result:
  [image]

Comment: Wow. This actually works even today, on Windows 10.

Comment: I've been thinking about this all day. @8m47x do you know how this works? How did you find it out?

Comment: Nope.. :) I found it out by accident in the past. It customized my stock school to my preferences. :)

Comment: I am able to change the background color, but the admins have blocked setting images, any ideas for windows 10, please share

Comment: I tried using bginfo, but of no use

Comment: this did the trick for me `By going to this location in the registry:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Inside, there's a key called Wallpaper. delete it and re-set the desktop background, and it work.`